# Getting last five recent days of a date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am trying to get the last recent five days of December 20th of 2022, also trying to convert UTC timezone to Pacific timezone (California timezone).

I tried this solution but it gives the last recent five days of Jan 20th 2023

My solution

```js
const recentFiveDays = new Array(5).fill().map((_, index) => {
  return new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date("2022-12-20").getDate() - index))
    .toISOString()
});
console.log(recentFiveDays);
```

and I get this output.

```
[
  '2023-01-19T07:13:55.565Z',
  '2023-01-18T07:13:55.565Z',
  '2023-01-17T07:13:55.566Z',
  '2023-01-16T07:13:55.566Z',
  '2023-01-15T07:13:55.566Z'
]
```

I am looking to get this output with pacific timezone (California timezone).

```
[
  '2022-12-19T07:13:55.565Z',
  '2022-12-18T07:13:55.565Z',
  '2022-12-17T07:13:55.566Z',
  '2022-12-16T07:13:55.566Z',
  '2022-12-15T07:13:55.566Z'
]
```

Comment: Do you really need 3 `new Date()` constructor calls in a single loop?

Comment: I mean I couldn't find another solution, if you could think of a better way of solving this problem share please

Comment: `new Date().setDate()` will get today's date and will just update the date part. So, it will have month as Jan. Just do the operations in 2 separate lines: `var date = new Date("2022-12-20"); date.setDate(date.getDate() - index); return date.toISOString()`

Comment: Could you please help with converting UTC timezone to PST timezone, I been struggling with that

Comment: If you really need it with a timezone information as ISO string you can use libs like [moment js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/).

Comment: What is the expected output? You are just setting the date here. Do you want the time to be local time in `PST` when this code runs?

Comment: I know there are some libraries help with that, but I am not allowed to use them because it is for my job, otherwise I would have used them

Comment: I am using `toISOString()` here which is giving me `UTC` timezone, I am not sure to convert that to `PST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's split it to parts:

`new Date("2022-12-20").getDate()` gives to you day of month it is 20.

You subtracting `n` days but in operation `new Date().setDate( ... )` you setting day of month for current date. So this code was working only in last month but will not work in future or past.

Answer that will change only few characters in your original code is

```
recentFiveDays = new Array(5).fill().map((_, index) => {
  return new Date(new Date("2022-12-20").setDate(new Date("2022-12-20").getDate() - index))
    .toISOString()
});
console.log(recentFiveDays);
```

i will print

```
"2022-12-20T00:00:00.000Z"
"2022-12-19T00:00:00.000Z"
"2022-12-18T00:00:00.000Z"
"2022-12-17T00:00:00.000Z"
"2022-12-16T00:00:00.000Z"
```

but I think you can invest time to learn `dayjs` library that is very lightweight and allow to write the same code in much more cleaner way.

---

With `dayjs` you can handle timezone problem using this code

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';
import timezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone';
dayjs.extend(utc)
dayjs.extend(timezone);

const tz = "America/Los_Angeles"

const recentFiveDays = new Array(5).fill(0).map((_, index) => {
    return dayjs("2022-12-20").tz(tz).subtract(index, 'days').format()
});
console.log(recentFiveDays);
```

and you will see

```
[
  '2022-12-19T15:00:00-08:00',
  '2022-12-18T15:00:00-08:00',
  '2022-12-17T15:00:00-08:00',
  '2022-12-16T15:00:00-08:00',
  '2022-12-15T15:00:00-08:00'
]
```

there is no `toIsoString` because you can't have timezone in ISO String by definition:

> The toISOString() method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format (ISO 8601), which is always 24 or 27 characters long (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ or ±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ, respectively). The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix Z.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: Super helpful information and great solution, I will def spend some time learning dayjs library.

thank you so much

Comment: _because you can't have timezone in ISO String by definition:_ is wrong. -- The JS built in `toISOString()` implementation just does not support alternative return values, it just returns the simplified extended ISO format. The dayjs `.format()` is different and supports more customisation. And it returns a valid ISO string depending on the extensions used, setttings made or the [arguments passed to the function](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format). The strings from the result shown in your example are all valid after ISO 8601.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue with your code is that you didnt used the date string inside the highlighted part. This is the final date object where your date is being decided

```
new Date(
  new Date("2022-12-20") // Here
    .setDate(new Date("2022-12-20").getDate() - index))
```

What you did ultimately is you took the date string as `"2022-12-20"`, decremented the date with index from that date and set it to current date. Instead of current date you should set it to `new Date("2022-12-20")`

Corrected the logic

Start with date `"2022-12-20"`
Get the date from the date object, decrement it with index, create a new date and convert it to ISO String

```js
const recentFiveDays = new Array(5).fill().map((_, index) =>  new Date(new Date("2022-12-20").setDate(new Date("2022-12-20").getDate() - index)));
console.log(recentFiveDays);
```

Comment: this is very helpful, but the second issue still there, this solution is showing local timezone or I am not sure what timezone that is `T00:00:00.000z`
is it possible to convert it to `PST`

Comment: @Rio0o.dev Can you please update the question how the final result looks in `pacific timezone (California timezone).`?